# Mysql Aliased tables in Anorm are not recognized

Tags: scala, anorm, playframework-2.4

**Update**
Created a runnable demo for this problem.

https://github.com/narayanjr/anorm_test

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

I am unable to access fields on an aliased table.  I keep getting error messages saying the field is not an option and the available fields are the base field name, or the `table_name'.field_name.  But not the aliased field name.  This makes it impossible to JOIN the same table twice and access all the fields.

```
var vendor_client_parser_1 = SqlParser.long("vid") ~ SqlParser.str("vname") ~ SqlParser.long("cid") ~ SqlParser.str("cname") map 
{
    case vid ~ vn ~ cid ~ cn => println(vid + "," + vn + "," + cid + "," + cn + ",")
}

var vendor_client_parser_2 = SqlParser.long("v.business_id") ~ SqlParser.str("v.name") ~ SqlParser.long("c.business_id") ~ SqlParser.str("c.name") map 
{
    case vid ~ vn ~ cid ~ cn => println(vid + "," + vn + "," + cid + "," + cn + ",")
}

var vendor_client_parser_3 = SqlParser.long(1) ~ SqlParser.str(2) ~ SqlParser.long(3) ~ SqlParser.str(4) map 
{
    case vid ~ vn ~ cid ~ cn => println(vid + "," + vn + "," + cid + "," + cn + ",")
}

DB.withConnection 
{
    implicit c =>
    var results = 
    SQL"""
        SELECT v.business_id AS vid, v.name AS vname, c.business_id AS cid, c.name AS cname
        FROM #$BUSINESS_CONNECTION_TABLE
        JOIN #$BUSINESS_TABLE AS v ON (vendor_id = v.business_id)
        JOIN #$BUSINESS_TABLE AS c ON (client_id = c.business_id)
        LIMIT 20
    """.as(vendor_client_parser.*)
}
```

Expected result:

```
1,  Vendor A,   10, Vendor K
2,  Vendor B,   11, Vendor L
2,  Vendor B,   1,  Vendor A
12, Vendor M,   3,  Vendor C
```

Result from vendor_client_parser_1:

```
10, Vendor K,   10, Vendor K
11, Vendor L,   11, Vendor L
1,  Vendor A,   1,  Vendor A
3,  Vendor C,   3,  Vendor C
```

Result from vendor_client_parser_2:

```
Execution exception[[AnormException: 'v.business_id' not found, available columns: business.business_id, business_id, business.name, name, business.business_id, business_id, business.name, name]]
```

Result from vendor_client_parser_3: (Same as expected)

```
1,  Vendor A,   10, Vendor K
2,  Vendor B,   11, Vendor L
2,  Vendor B,   1,  Vendor A
12, Vendor M,   3,  Vendor C
```

vendor_client_parser_3 works but it relies on using index instead of names.  I dis like using indexes because If I mess up an index I might still get a valid response back and not notice.  If I mess up a name the column wont exist and I will know something is wrong.

Is there something I am missing?  Is there any way to achieve the results I need without having to rely on using the index?

- Play Scala 2.4.1
- Anorm 2.5.0

**Update:**
If I do not alias the columns and use `vendor_client_parser_2` I get the same result as when the columns are alias.

Modified Query:

```
SQL"""
    SELECT v.business_id, v.name, c.business_id, c.name
    FROM #$BUSINESS_CONNECTION_TABLE
    JOIN #$BUSINESS_TABLE AS v ON (vendor_id = v.business_id)
    JOIN #$BUSINESS_TABLE AS c ON (client_id = c.business_id)
    LIMIT 20
""".as(vendor_client_parser_2.*)
```

Result with vendor_client_parser_2.*:

```
Execution exception[[AnormException: 'v.business_id' not found, available columns: business.business_id, business_id, business.name, name, business.business_id, business_id, business.name, name]]
```

I also tested it with a single table aliased and it refuses to see the aliased table name

Single Table Test:

```
SQL"""
    SELECT v.business_id, v.name, business_id, name
    FROM #$BUSINESS_TABLE AS v 
    LIMIT 20
""".as(test_parser.*)
```

test_parser:

```
var test_parser = SqlParser.long("v.business_id") ~ SqlParser.str("v.name") ~ SqlParser.long("business_id") ~ SqlParser.str("name") map 
{
    case vid ~ vn ~ cid ~ cn => println(vid + "," + vn + "," + cid + "," + cn + ",")
}
```

Result:

```
[AnormException: 'v.business_id' not found, available columns: business.business_id, business_id, business.name, name, business.business_id, business_id, business.name, name]
```

I then tested if aliased columns are accessible by both their original and aliased names.

Test Aliased columns:

```
SQL"""
    SELECT business_id AS vid, name AS vname
    FROM #$BUSINESS_TABLE 
    LIMIT 20
""".as(test_parser_2.*)
```

test_parser_2:

```
var test_parser_2 = SqlParser.long("business_id") ~ SqlParser.str("name") ~ SqlParser.long("vid") ~ SqlParser.str("vname") map 
{
    case vid ~ vn ~ cid ~ cn => println(vid + "," + vn + "," + cid + "," + cn + ",")
}
```

This test did not error out and it properly pulled in values as business_id and vid. As well as name and vname.

I forced it to error out so it would give me a list of column names.  And it does seem like Anorm doesn't offer the non-aliased names as suggestions but they do work in this case.

```
[AnormException: 'forceError' not found, available columns: business.business_id, vid, business.name, vname]
```

I also tried not using SqlParser.

```
var businesses = SQL"""
    SELECT v.business_id AS vid, v.name AS vname, c.business_id AS cid, c.name AS cname
    FROM #$BUSINESS_CONNECTION_TABLE
    JOIN #$BUSINESS_TABLE AS v ON (vendor_id = v.business_id)
    JOIN #$BUSINESS_TABLE AS c ON (client_id = c.business_id)
    LIMIT 20
""".fold(List[(Long, String, Long, String)]())
    { 
        (list, row) =>
        list :+ (row[Long]("v.business_id"), row[String]("v.name"), row[Long]("c.business_id"), row[String]("c.name")) //attempt_1    
        //list :+ (row[Long]("vid"), row[String]("vname"), row[Long]("cid"), row[String]("cname")) //attempt_2        
    }
```

If I use attempt_1 I get this error which as you suggested shouldn't work.

```
Left('v.business_id' not found, available columns: business.business_id, vid, business.name, vname, business.business_id, cid, business.name, cname)))
```

If I use attempt_2, I get the same results as `vendor_client_parser_1`

```
10, Vendor K,   10, Vendor K
11, Vendor L,   11, Vendor L
1,  Vendor A,   1,  Vendor A
3,  Vendor C,   3,  Vendor C
```

If I do not alias the columns and use this same method

```
SQL"""
    SELECT v.business_id, v.name, c.business_id, c.name
    FROM #$BUSINESS_CONNECTION_TABLE
    JOIN #$BUSINESS_TABLE AS v ON (vendor_id = v.business_id)
    JOIN #$BUSINESS_TABLE AS c ON (client_id = c.business_id)
    LIMIT 20
""".fold(List[(Long, String, Long, String)]())
    { 
        (list, row) =>
        list :+ (row[Long]("v.business_id"), row[String]("v.name"), row[Long]("c.business_id"), row[String]("c.name")) //Attempt_3            
    }
```

Using this query without aliasing the columns causes this error,

```
Left('v.business_id' not found, available columns: business.business_id, business_id, business.name, name, business.business_id, business_id, business.name, name)))
```

I then tested a simple aliased tabled using this method

```
SQL"""
    SELECT v.business_id, v.name
    FROM #$BUSINESS_TABLE AS v
    LIMIT 20
""".fold(List[(Long, String)]())
    { 
        (list, row) =>
        list :+ (row[Long]("v.business_id"), row[String]("v.name")) //simple_attempt_1       
    }
```

I get the same error

```
Left(List(java.lang.RuntimeException: Left('v.business_id' not found, available columns: business.business_id, business_id, business.name, name)))
```

So as far as I can tell it isn't possible to access fields that are part of an aliased table if the same table is used twice using the field names instead of index.

**Update 2:**

I tried reversing the order of fields in the SQL so it was `c.business_id AS cid, c.name AS cname, v.business_id AS vid, v.name AS vname` and rerunning `vendor_client_parser_1`.  It gave me the inverse results

Result from vendor_client_parser_1 with mysql fields switched:

```
1,  Vendor A,   1,  Vendor A
2,  Vendor B,   2,  Vendor B
2,  Vendor B,   2,  Vendor B
12, Vendor M,   12, Vendor M
```

When I force an error and it shows me possible fields I get these,

Fields in original order:

```
Left('forceError' not found, available columns: business.business_id, vid, business.name, vname, business.business_id, cid, business.name, cname)
```

Fields in switched order:

```
Left('forceError' not found, available columns: business.business_id, cid, business.name, cname, business.business_id, vid, business.name, vname)
```

This makes me think this scenario is happening.

> In case several columns are found with same name in query result, for example columns named code in both Country and CountryLanguage tables, there can be ambiguity. By default a mapping like following one will use the last column:

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.1/ScalaAnorm

If you look at the suggested fields `business.business_id` and `business.name` occur twice because the table is referenced twice.  It seems like Anorm is associating the last occurrence of `business.business_id` and `business.name` with both aliases.

**Update**
Created a runnable demo for this problem.
https://github.com/narayanjr/anorm_test

Comment: As soon as you alias the column, it's not accessible with the orginal name. If you want to use it, don't alias it, or have the column twice (with & w/o alias).

Comment: @cchantep  I tried changing things as you suggested.  The results have been added to the question.

Comment: If you look at the details of the error, you will see that the FQDN of the columns are not calculated with the alias the of table, there `v`, but only with the original table name. Simpler is better: make sure your SELECT is projecting values with unique column or alias names, and just use these simple unique name, here just `"business_id"` and `"name"`.

Comment: @cchantep I have tried that and it doesn't seem to work correctly.  Take a look at `vendor_client_parser_1` and the results I got from that.  That is using unique aliased names but the result is wrong.  the value of `cid` and `cname` is being used for both `vid`and  `vname.  Anything to do with this? "In case several columns are found with same name in query result, for example columns named code in both Country and CountryLanguage tables, there can be ambiguity. **By default a mapping like following one will use the last column**" https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.1/ScalaAnorm

Comment: Support of column aliases is tested in Anorm. Make sure all the names are unique, and as suggested in case of error check which names are available (in error details).

Comment: @cchantep I have made sure all of the names are unique and checked the names available and I am using the ones suggested.  I still get the wrong results.  I made a simple example app demonstrating the issue if you wouldn't mind looking at it. https://github.com/narayanjr/anorm_test

Its a single controller which creates two tables, inserts, then demonstrates the issue.

Comment: You can add a ticket at https://github.com/playframework/anorm/issues

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried it in 2.4, but you could possibly use a parser method to generate the column name for you, rather than a variable. My approach would be something like the following:

```
case class BusinessConnection(vendor_id: Int, client_id: Int)
case class Business(id: Int, name: String)
case class VendorClient(vendor: Business, client: Business)

object VendorClient {
  val businessConnectionP =
    get[Int]("vendor_id") ~
      get[Int]("client_id") map {
        case vendor_id ~ client_id =>
          BusinessConnection(vendor_id, client_id)
      }
  def businessP(alias: String) =
    getAliased[Int](alias + ".id") ~
      getAliased[String](alias + ".name") map {
        case id ~ name =>
          Business(id, name)
      }
  val vendorClientP =
    businessP("v") ~ businessP("c") map {
      case business ~ client =>
        VendorClient(business, client)
    }
  val sqlSelector = "v.id, v.name, c.id, c.name"
  def all() = DB.withConnection { implicit c =>
    SQL(s"""
      select $sqlSelector
      from businessConnection
        join business as v on vendor_id=v.id
        join business as c on client_id=c.id
      """).as(vendorClientP *)
  }
}
```